# Selecting a value from a custom property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select a value and store it into a variable. Here is how it looks like:

```
<a href="#" video-id="somevalue">My link</a>
```

not I want to do smth like this:

```
$('a').on(click, function(){
var videoId = a[video-id].val();
});
```

output should be :

```
console.log(videoId);
somevalue
```

**Update**

```
video-id="this is changeable"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put `a` and `click` in `quotes`. You can use `.attr()` or `.data()` to get the desired `attribute value`'

**Using `.attr()`**

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){
var videoId = $(this).attr('video-id');
    alert(videoId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" video-id="somevalue">My link</a>
```

**Using `.data()`**

To use `.data()` you have to prefix you attribute with `data` e.d `data-id` instead of `video-id`

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){
var videoId = $(this).data('id');
    alert(videoId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-id="somevalue">My link</a>
```

Comment: Nice answer! But same as mine. I don't understand the difference!

Comment: @PraveenKumar `click` should be in `quotes`. `var videoId = $('a').data("video-id");` this is not gona work

Comment: The OP is so careless about using the variables and values! Fine, I should have said informed!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use:

```
var videoId = a.attr("video-id");
```

Or, better stick with `data-*` attributes and give:

```
<a href="#" data-video-id="somevalue">My link</a>
var videoId = a.data("video-id");
```

And please change:

```
$(a)
// to
$("a")
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I'm quite in a hurry :)

Comment: The accepted answer and my answer are the same, right? Why did it not work?

Comment: Nor yours nor his answer were correct. His answer lead me to a correct one :)

Comment: Okay fine. As you say! `:D`